# STM32 L1 Bootloader: how to set the reset vector

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, bootloader

I am trying to program a STM32 L1(51C8Ux) via the standard bootloader and when I do the memory gets written to, but the code doesn't execute (after reset that is).  I assume as part of the memory erase, I have overwritten the reset vector.  Where does the reset vector reside and what am I supposed to write to it?

I have been referencing RM0038 (Reference manual) and AN3155 (Bootloader command set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reset vector is the second word (32 bit) in the interrupt vector table. It must be an odd value (thumb bit is set).

Comment: What is the value that is loaded at that location? What does that memory location control?

Comment: RTFM: RM0038, Chapter 10.1.2 "Interrupt and exception vectors". The value points to the first instruction of the startup code, which initialises data memory and calls `main()`.